# use perl to replace unit timestamp within text string

Tags: regex, perl, unix-timestamp

Ok, I a have a data file with two columns of data. They are RecordNumber and Notes. They are separated by pipes and look like this.

```
Record1|1234567890 username notes notes notes notes 1254184921 username notes notes notes notes|
```

... This goes on for thousands of records.

Using a perl script (and possible some regex) I need to take the notes column and parse it out to make 3 new columns separated with pipes to load into a table. The columns need to be `Note_Date|Note_Username|Note_Text`.

The 10-digit string of numbers throughout the notes column is a unix timestamp. My second task is to take this and convert it to a regular timestamp. Please, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Is that the exact data format?  Why is there a "`Record1|`" preceding the first record, but not the second and subsequent records?  Is there a newline or anything else separating the records besides a simple space character?  And finally, what have you come up with so far, and where are you stuck?

Comment: It is always nice if there is some real sample data to test against. Is there any chance you could provide some?

Comment: You are accumulating votes to close because you are not trying to help us to help you. This won't help if you want to come back for help a second time

Comment: mob - I did not really know where to start
David0 - The reason there is not a Record2 is because that was an example of multiple notes on one record
Borodin - sorry, I got busy working, didn't really have time to sit and stare at this page to look for updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to modify this for your needs:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
        my @a = split(/\|/);
        while ($a[1]=~/\s*(\d+)\s+(\w+)\s+([^0-9]*)/g) {
                my ($t, $u, $n) = ($1, $2, $3);
                $t = localtime($t);
                print $a[0], "|$t $u $n|\n";
        }
}
```